# Why is using find() on these arrays so slow when within a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Background: I came across this issue whilst dealing with arrays of large and small numbers using the findIndex function. I have given a minimum working example below. I can avoid the issue, but I just don't understand why the issue exists in the first place.

In node.js (v12.16.3), why does getting rid of the for loop around the find function in this example cause the performance to increase dramatically? (5600 ms reduced to 250 ms)

The issue does not appear if I change the value in the second array from 1e10 to 1e9 or less, or if I change the value in the first array from 1 to 1e10 or more.

```js
const nSims = 1e8

const arrays = [];
arrays[0] = [1];
arrays[1] = [1e10];

console.time('a')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        arrays[j].find((value) => value > 0);
    }
}
console.timeEnd('a') // 5600 ms

console.time('b')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    arrays[0].find((value) => value > 0);
    arrays[1].find((value) => value > 0);
}
console.timeEnd('b') // 250 ms
```

Comment: Let's back up first: what on earth are you trying to actually _do_ here? (and on a practical note, which version of Node? Because there are _many_)

Comment: Cause maybe `arrays[0]` can be inlined while `arrays[j]` cannot ...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is just a minimum working example of an issue I noticed whilst dealing with arrays of large numbers and the find function.

Comment: @JonasWilms Why would the issue go away if I change the relative sizes of the numbers contained within the arrays?

Comment: Because one might be represented internally as an array of integers while the other would be represented internally as an array of doubles. Looping over arrays with different internal representations will probably require less specialised code that is slower. I've tagged the question with [v8] so @jmrk will have a look at it :-)

Comment: @AlexRoss yes but also no: your code is blind-iterating over 100000000 array positions in the outer loop, which makes _no sense_ if this is a real code mcve. Why is it not iterating over array entries that are guaranteed to exist? (because JS arrays are not contiguous like C++ arrays, you can have something in _key_ 0  and something in _key_ 100000, and nothing in between. Arrays in JS are just objects with keys that are allowed to be numbers, and several built-in functions that rely on the array's content to exclusively use those numerical keys)

Comment: @Mike the outer loop is just for the benchmark repetition. No non-existing array indices are accessed, and there are no sparse arrays in the code.

Comment: Basically, even if this is an interesting quirk with a fascinating spec-level explanation, the fact that you ran into this is almost certainly a sign that what you were doing didn't account for how JS does things. For example: if you _really_ need contiguous integer arrays, then this code should not use plain arrays at all, you should be using typed arrays, and then if you still hit this behaviour, now there's something truly weird going on. But if you're playing fast and loose with typing, unexpected behaviour is definitely to be expected.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It looks like you have misread the example code. This is not iterating over 1e8 array positions... it is iterating over 1 array position (for simplicity). The test is performed 1e8 times in order to show the difference in performance. In practice I am accessing an array of 1000 elements, but adding that in would have made the example more complicated than this minimum working example.

Comment: gotcha. That still leaves the note on typed arrays though: if you _really_ need integers (or floats or doubles of course), step one is to not use plain arrays but use the typed array appropriate to your data.

Comment: @Bergi This seems to make the most sense from my layman's perspective and fits with some of my own thoughts on this

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, I didn't know typed arrays were a thing. I will definitely look into this and keep it in mind in future. I didn't think a nested array would care about the contents of another nested array, but I guess I was wrong about that.

Comment: If we test this code in a browser, we still have the issue, so the problem is not in Node (and typings) itself

Answer (score 6):

V8 developer here.

The "slow case" is the true cost of calling `Array.find` with a callback: for every element, the built-in implementation of `Array.find` performs a call to the provided callback. Aside from doing this basic work that you asked it to do, the implementation is actually pretty optimized, both the `Array.find` built-in and the supplied callback.

The fast case benefits from certain additional optimizations in V8: if a call to `Array.find` has only ever seen arrays of the same type (including internal representation, see below), then there's some special handling in the type feedback collection system and the optimizing compiler to emit a special inlined version of it, which in particular has the follow-on benefit that it can also inline the provided callback, specialized for this type of array. As you can see here, this optimization provides a massive speed boost when it is applicable.

The reason that `[1e9]` and `[1e10]` are different types of arrays under the hood is because `1e9` is a 30-bit integer, so V8 internally chooses "small integer" (aka "smi", 31-bit signed int) representation for the array's elements. `1e10`, however, would require 34 bits, so V8 chooses double (64-bit floating point) representation for the array elements. So if the *same* occurrence of `Array.find` encounters both `[1e9]` (or `[1]` for that matter) *and* `[1e10]`, it decides "I've seen more than one type of array here, inlining more than one special case probably costs more than it's worth, let's use the generic version". You could say that this decision is a bit overly pessimistic in this case, but such is the nature of heuristics: engines need rules to decide what to do, and since they can't predict what your code will do in the future, they just have to make some guess -- which could turn out to be a good guess, or a not so good guess :-)

It's not related to having a loop per se; looping over the list of arrays is just one way of making the same `Array.find` encounter several array types. You could trigger the fallback to the generic path without a loop by using a function that's called with different inputs; or you could have a loop (that loops over something else) while still staying on the fast path.

---

@Anton wrote:

> It seems, that find method has some problems.

I wouldn't put it that way. It's not easy for an engine to optimize `Array.find` to the same degree as a hand-written for-loop -- for instance, because an engine generally can't inline user-provided callbacks into built-in functions. As explained above, V8 knows enough tricks to be able to pull off such inlining in some situations, but not always.

This is far from the only case where a hand-written replacement for a built-in function can achieve faster performance; in many cases this is because the built-in functions are more general (i.e.: support more weird corner cases) than the hand-written replacement. It's also the case that outside of targeted microbenchmarks it is fairly rare (though certainly not impossible) to find a case where these differences actually matter.

Comment: This is the answer I expected from you :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Maybe this is not the correct answer, but it is just a very big comment (I need code snippets to illustrate).*

This is example from the question (it takes more that 5 seconds for the `a`, and less than second for `b`):

```js
const nSims = 1e8

const arrays = [];
arrays[0] = [1];
arrays[1] = [1e10];

console.time('a')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        arrays[j].find((value) => value > 0);
    }
}
console.timeEnd('a') // 5600 ms

console.time('b')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    arrays[0].find((value) => value > 0);
    arrays[1].find((value) => value > 0);
}
console.timeEnd('b') // 250 ms
```

This happens if we change `1e10` to `1e9` ("magic" here):

```js
const nSims = 1e8

const arrays = [];
arrays[0] = [1];
arrays[1] = [1e9];

console.time('a')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        arrays[j].find((value) => value > 0);
    }
}
console.timeEnd('a') // 5600 ms

console.time('b')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    arrays[0].find((value) => value > 0);
    arrays[1].find((value) => value > 0);
}
console.timeEnd('b') // 250 ms
```

It seems, that `find` method has some problems. Here what happens if we replace it with `for` iteration (`a` and `b` becomes close, and less than 1 second):

```js
const nSims = 1e8

const arrays = [];
arrays[0] = [1];
arrays[1] = [1e10];

function find(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) return arr[i];
  }
}

console.time('a')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        find(arrays[j]);
    }
}
console.timeEnd('a')

console.time('b')
for (var i = 0; i < nSims; i++) {
    find(arrays[0]);
    find(arrays[1]);
}
console.timeEnd('b')
```